# Spring security restful web service token based authentication

Tags: json, spring-security, restful-authentication, access-token

I'm writing restful web service that is returning json and use Spring MVC for that. I'm using Spring 3.x.
Now I want to add a login method, that will retrieve user name and password and return access token so that client can use that token further for calling other methods. I'm thinking that this token should have a finite life time.
Is there a good sample of doing that? Do I need spring security for that at all? And again, a good sample would be much appreciated.